# Is there a way to use adb to tap on a secondary Android display

Tags: android, adb, android-uiautomator

I know there are ways to target a secondary screen like this:

`adb shell am start com.google.android.calculator --display 1`

`adb shell screencap -d 1 -p /sdcard/screencapture.png`

Is there a way to tap on a a secondary screen? For now this seem to only go to display 0:

`adb shell input tap x y`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this does it. The issue I have with it not working was that the screen coordinates in the dump XML were taking into account the X axis from the display 0, but the ADB do not do that, so they needed to be subtracted.

```
adb shell input -d 1 tap x y
```